# Ligthswitch 2013 Set value ACB when launching from another screen

Tags: autocomplete, lightswitch-2013

I have a search screen called TimesheetsByjob. This is based on a query called TSByJob and has one parameter called JobID. Normally the user will just open this screen and select a job. The ACB's JobID field is bound to the query parameter JobID.

I now want to add a button in the timesheet entry form to open this search screen from a button. Obviously, I know what the JobID is, so I want to (and the user will expect me to)  preset the JobID instead of them having to select it from the ACB.

In the timesheet entry form my button as this is the Execute code:

```
 int JobID = TimesheetProperty.Job.ID;
 Application.Current.ShowSearchTSByJob();
```

I want to pass a param, but the method doesn't expect one.

Is there a way to overload the method to accept a param (if so where would I do that), or is there another way to do it other than making a 100% duplicate of the search screen and using a local property?

Regards

mark

Answer (score 0):

In your `SearchTSByJob` screen, add a local property of the type you require. In that local property's Properties, check "Is Parameter".

[image: is parameter]

Now you can pass a parameter to that screen. If you have multiple, Intellisense will tell you the order it expects.

```
int JobID = TimesheetProperty.Job.ID;
Application.Current.ShowSearchTSByJob(JobID);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did try this, but the got stuck somewhere, will have to revisit it, was a few days ago and a lot has happened since then. I guess if I do this I will have to change everywhere that calls that screen and pass null and then write something in the created or initdataworkspace method to handle null vs value